# CDK: How to use same Iam role between 2 different stacks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

I have a stack which creates 2 different codebuild projects.

```
const codeBuildProject = new CodeBuildProjects(this, 
    'pipelineCodeBuildProjects', {
          PlanProjectName: 'one-project',
          DeployProjectName: 'second-project'
          OneProjectIamRoleName: 'iam-role',
          twoProjectIamRoleName: 'iam-role'
        })
```

This is stack class

```
export class CodeBuildProjects extends cdk.Stack {
    public readonly plan: codeBuildProject;
    public readonly deploy: codeBuildProject;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: CodeBuildProjectProps) {

        super(scope, id, props);


        this.plan = new codeBuildProject(this, 'one-project', {
            projectName: props.oneProjectName,
            description: 'some desc',
            buildspec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject(yaml.parse(fs.readFileSync('codebuild-buildspec/plan.yml', 'utf8'))),
            roleName: props.projectOneIamRoleName
        })

        this.deploy = new codeBuildProject(this, 'two-project', {
            projectName: props.twoProjectName,
            description: 'some desc',
            buildspec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject(yaml.parse(fs.readFileSync('codebuild-buildspec/apply.yml', 'utf8'))),
            roleName: props.projectTwoIamRoleName
        })

    };

}
```

Both the roleName are same as I want to share the use the same Iam Roles for both the code build projects.

Here is my constructor for the codebuild project

```
 constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: PipelineCodeBuildprops) {

        super(scope, id, props);

        this.project = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, 'codebuild-project', {
            projectName: props.projectName,
            description: props.description, // a Bucket used as a source in CodePipeline must be versioned
            environment: {
                computeType: ComputeType.SMALL,
                buildImage: LinuxBuildImage.AMAZON_LINUX_2_4,
            },
            buildSpec: props.buildspec,
            role: new iam.Role(this, 'codebuild-iam-role', {
                roleName: props.roleName,
                assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('codebuild.amazonaws.com'),
                description: 'some desc'
            })
        });
    }
```

Upon deploying it throws an error in plan project that iam role already exists in deploy project stack

Comment: The OP title refers to sharing a Role "between two different stacks".  But there seems to be a single stack in your example code.  What am I missing?

Comment: Cloudformation is creating 2 stacks, I have verified this is in the console.

`the stack named planprojectxxxxx failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: iam-role already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:region-xxxxx:xxxxxx:stack/deployxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Because you are doing new in construct it is trying to create 2 times, either create the role upfront and then refer them in the constructor using fromRoleName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Augunrik Answer is the motivation for this answer. I fixed my problem by

Creating role as seperate stack and importing the role in each codebuild project

role stack

```
const manualRole = new IamRole(app, 'iam-role', {
  ServiceRoleName: getResourceName(app, 'role', 'role-name', env),
})
```

Importing role

```
this.plan = new codeBuildProject(this, 'one-project', {
            projectName: props.oneProjectName,
            description: 'some desc',
            buildspec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject(yaml.parse(fs.readFileSync('codebuild-buildspec/plan.yml', 'utf8'))),
            role: Role.fromRoleName(this, 'import', manualRole.codeBuildIamRole.role.roleName),

    })

    this.deploy = new codeBuildProject(this, 'two-project', {
        projectName: props.twoProjectName,
        description: 'some desc',
        buildspec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject(yaml.parse(fs.readFileSync('codebuild-buildspec/apply.yml', 'utf8'))),
      role: Role.fromRoleName(this, 'import', manualRole.codeBuildIamRole.role.roleName),

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The role is created twice and needs to be shared between them. This can simply done by caching the role.

Example:

```
export class CodeBuildProjects extends cdk.Stack {
    public readonly plan: codeBuildProject;
    public readonly deploy: codeBuildProject;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: CodeBuildProjectProps) {

        super(scope, id, props);

        //
        var role = // CREATE ROLE HERE

        this.plan = new codeBuildProject(this, 'one-project', {
            projectName: props.oneProjectName,
            description: 'some desc',
            buildspec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject(yaml.parse(fs.readFileSync('codebuild-buildspec/plan.yml', 'utf8'))),
            role: role
        })

        this.deploy = new codeBuildProject(this, 'two-project', {
            projectName: props.twoProjectName,
            description: 'some desc',
            buildspec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject(yaml.parse(fs.readFileSync('codebuild-buildspec/apply.yml', 'utf8'))),
            role: role
        })

    };

}
```

If you really want to share a role between two stacks then this can also be done. One stack create the role, the other one imports it again via:

```
var role = iam.fromRoleArn(this, id, roleArn)
```

Comment: doing you way says it would create a cyclic reference which is obvious

Comment: Which way do you mean? I described two. There is no cyclic reference in either way.

Comment: if I am trying trying your first way, cdk complaints that it creates a cyclic reference where iam role is dependent on plan project inside my stack

Comment: Could it be that CodeBuildProject extends from Stack? This is not mentioned in the question and I assumed that these are constructs. If they are stacks, the role may need to be in another stack and dependencies explicitly defined.

Comment: I am sorry Augunril, from not mentioning it that these are stacks.